# How to get overall count of distinct records from ktable in ksql

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I have created a stream in KSQL as shown below.

```
create stream incident_1  (fruitName VARCHAR) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='test_incident',VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

Say I have a topic with following records in the stream

```
fruitName
---------
apple
orange
banana
apple
orange
```

I tried of getting the count for individual records by creating a table in KSQL, say the output is

```
select fruitName,count(*) from incident_2 group by fruitName;

    fruitName     count
    ---------    --------
    apple          2
    orange         2
    banana         1
```

I have also tried writing JAVA logic in streaming application code instead of KSQL. But this will be helpful for fewer data. In future we get over 100k records, at that time it takes much time for all these iterations which effects the slow of code. So I thought not to use this. Here is the code

```
static HashSet<String> hash_incident = new HashSet<String>();

// Adding elements into HashSet usind add() 
hash_incident.add(new_key);

System.out.println("incident_count  "+hash_incident.size());

count_unique_notification+=1;
System.out.println("keyyyyyy"+new_key+
"helllllllllllllllllllllllo"+count_unique_notification);
```

[image]

But, what I want Exactly is, the overall count of distinct records as

```
total_distinctt_fruits_count
-----------------------------
       3
```

So, is there any other way in KSQL ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of ksqlDB you're running, but the latest has a `COUNT_DISTINCT` function, which looks to be a perfect fit for what you're wanting to achieve.

```
-- Your source stream:
create stream incident_1 (
    fruitName VARCHAR
  ) WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC='test_incident',
    VALUE_FORMAT='JSON'
  );


-- `COUNT_DISTINCT` works per topic-partition. 
-- So if you want a _global_ count, then you must ensure you have only a single partition.
-- This step can be avoided if topic `test_incident` only has a single partition
CREATE STREAM single_partition AS
  WITH (PARTITIONS = 1)
  SELECT * FROM incident_1;


-- Now that we have a single source partition, we can create a table with the counts:
-- Set partitions to 1 as all output is on a single key, so only need 1 partition.
-- And GROUP BY a constant/literal so that all results end up on the same key - so you get a _global_ count.
-- And use `COUNT_DISTINCT` to count the distinct fruit:
CREATE TABLE DISTINCT_COUNTS 
  WITH (PARTITIONS = 1) AS
  SELECT
    1 AS K,
    COUNT_DISTINCT(fruitName) AS NUM_DISTINCT_FRUITS
  FROM single_partition
  GROUP BY 1;
```